# Pinning down random JS ID on datepicker

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I am building a web scraper and trying to send a date value to a date picker, instead of navigating through the calendar click by click.

The ID for the start and end date range is randomly generated on each new session (I think from the JS). It looks like this "06fb5372-9808-4e0a-8d68-bd43707c52a3"

How can I get the new ID each time and pass that through with a specified value with sendkeys?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
startdate = "1/1/2020"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='06fb5372-9808-4e0a-8d68-bd43707c52a3']")
send_keys(startdate)
```

I see in the website HTML code that there is a label for >Start< and >End<
I've attached a screenshot with those highlighted.

This code looks like:

```
<label for="06fb5372-9808-4e0a-8d68-bd43707c52a3" class="k-label">Start</label>
<label for="06fb5372-9808-4e0a-8d68-bd43707c52a3" class="k-label">End</label>
```

How would I go about identifying the >Start< and >End< labels to then send the associated random IDs from those lines to the find_element by XPATH?

Thanks!

[Code Screenshot /w highlighted IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K07Se.png)

Comment: //label[@class='k-label' and text()='Start'] should be a viable xpath.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and it didn't work for me. I'm sure I am missing something.  (StartDate_ID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@class='k-label' and text()='Start']")
print(StartDate_ID.get_attribute('for'))) -  I am trying to obtain the string in for='xxxx' from this, and then pass that to a variable.

Comment: This is the error I get: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[@class='k-label' and text()='Start']"}